# Not able to run streamlit app due to altair

Tags: python, libraries, streamlit

I have installed `streamlit==1.18.1` and `streamlit-extras` in my [Conda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conda_(package_manager)) virtual environment and am using Visual Studio Code for development. I have confirmed that I am using the Python interpreter in my virtual environment.

But whenever I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
import altair as alt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘altair’
```

I have tried using `pip install altair` and also `pip install alt`.

But I am still getting the same error.

I have added the path variable of my virtual environment.

Comment: Is "import altair as alt" actually part of the error message?